# Handle data sent from back-end on front-end javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've got a NodeJS Express back-end.

When it receives a GET request to the route `/messages/`, it fetches the messages in the database, builds an array called `messageList` and populate the view, which is then rendered to the user with no problem.

Here's the code that handles the resquest, in the Express router `messages.js`:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const messageList = await req.app.get('messageHandler').get();
    res.render('messages', { messageList: messageList });
});
```

And here is part the view template in the `messages.ejs` file:

```
<table>
    <% for (var i = 0; i < messageList.length; i++) { %>
        <tr id="msg-<%= i %>"><td><%= messageList[i].title %></td></tr>
    <% } %>
<table>
```

It all works perfectly fine and smooth.

However, I'd like to eventually handle these messages in the front-end side javascript, to apply a filter by suppressing the `<tr>` with a given `id` property.

Is there a way to pass the array `messageList` to the front-end javascript, or to load it as a javascript array when the page is loaded??

Thanks in advance! =)

Comment: I don't understand, isn't messageList already JavaScript array?

Comment: Simply filter the `messageList` array instead of using a `for` loop.

Comment: @OrAssayag Yes, but on the back-end part.
I want to have a copy of it on the front end, so I can handle it.

Comment: @GabrielLupu Let's say I implement a search field where the user can input the value he/she's looking for... I want to do it in the front-end, without having to make a new http request for it to be applied.

Comment: How about `<script>const messageList = <%= messageList %></script>`?

Comment: On the client just hold them in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Vinas from one of your comment

*@OrAssayag Yes, but on the back-end part. I want to have a copy of it on the front end, so I can handle i*

and

*@GabrielLupu Let's say I implement a search field where the user can input the value he/she's looking for... I want to do it in the front-end, without having to make a new http request for it to be applied*

You want the application response to handle `res.render() & res.json()`

which would throw an error
so why not write another get route

like  this

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const messageList = await req.app.get('messageHandler').get();
    res.render('messages', { messageList: messageList });
});

router.get('/api', async (req, res) => {
    const messageList = await req.app.get('messageHandler').get();
    res.json( messageList );
});
```

then its look something like this on the client

```
<table>
    <% for (var i = 0; i < messageList.length; i++) { %>
        <tr id="msg-<%= i %>"><td><%= messageList[i].title %></td></tr>
    <% } %>
<table>

<script>
fetch('/api')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
</script>
```